# Stain in mineral oil finish

Tags: finish

I have a wood(White Pine)project that I want put
mineral oil on and was wondering if I could add a
small amount of wood stain to the oil before I applied it

Comment: You'd want to use a purpose-made dye. Results would be unpredictable at best when adding full wood stain.

Comment: I would want to use an oil with pigment in the oil there are lots of brands and colors on the market colors range from black to white and everything in between, mixing 2 different products may not provide the results you want and could end up blotching or spotting like when oil and water are mixed.

Comment: Best to stain it before applying the mineral oil. If you mix stain in with the oil it would not penetrate and would be constantly transferring stain to whatever it touched.

Answer (score 1):

I mix oil stains (and alkaloid oil stains) with both mineral and linseed oil all the time for both interior and exterior use!  If you want to match a color or make your own colors just create a practice piece if possible and mix and apply until you get what you want.  It works, it’s cheap and you have lots of opportunity to adjust and play with it until you get what you want versus most any other approach.  Hint: Start a “blend” of stains in clear oil with the lightest first and build up with the dark stain….it’s hard to go light once’s it’s too dark!